# C++ function returning copy of the object from an array of objects. Is this the default behaviour?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

The program I am writing has grown pretty complex therefore I am not able to provide the actual code but the following is the exact situation

Theres a class,  Location, location has a counter `(int associatedLocations;)` that keeps count of the number of locations that can be directly reached from that location (initially 0), and a routine

```
setConnectedLocations(int value)
```

that can change the value of associatedLocations variable.
Also another routine that fetches the value of `associatedLocations` variable

```
int getAssociatedLocationsCount(){
    return associatedLocations;
}
```

In the main function I have an array of such locations.

```
Location locations[5];
```

also a function that returns a location from the array based on the index that is passed in as parameter to the function

```
Location getLocation(int index){
    return(locations[index]);
}
```

Now, when I try to do something like this

```
getLocation(0).setAssociatedLocations(5);
cout<<getLocation(0).getAssociatedLocationCount();
```

The output is 0.

even on doing something like `locations[0].getAssoicatedLocationCount();`
the output is 0;

But when I do this

```
locations[0].setAssociatedLocations(5);
cout<<locations[0].getAssociatedLocationCount();
```

The output is 5, which is what was required.

Does the function `getLocation(int index)` makes a copy of the object in the array and then returns it? is this the default/expected behaviour?

Comment: C++ uses value semantics by default, which means that objects are copied around. If you want reference semantics, you have to ask for it (either by using references or some form of indirection (like pointers)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the function getLocation(int index) makes a copy of the object in the array and then returns it?

Yes with such function signature it returns a copy.

> is this the default/expected behaviour?

Yes it is expected behavior. If you want to modify that object in array return reference instead:

```
Location &getLocation(int index);
```

Comment: Just wandering, how deep(shallow?) this copy is?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Depends on how the copy constructor of `Location` is defined.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The defaulted copy constructor is shallow yes, but if the internals of `Location` don't have any kind of indirection then "shallow" and "deep" are the same thing. In C++, a shallow copy is one that just copies the members without following any levels of indirection.